# How to change default currency in Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart?

Tags: php, laravel, shopping-cart

I have been implementing a shopping cart in Laravel and I came across this awesome library `Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart` but I want to change the default currency from `$` to `₹` . How can I do this? I have searched the whole documentation but couldn't find a way to do this.

Comment: Hi, do you sure this package has a default currency? I think it has only a value of price.

Comment: In my case, when I use this package, I only strore the user cart without currency and shows information about cart for user with utf-8 currency symbol.

Comment: @OlegNurutdinov Can you provide a detailed answer?

Comment: check my answer, hope it helps.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'll check [class Cart in this package](https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart/blob/master/src/Cart.php) (string 89, for example). Where's no attributes on `add()` method that say us something about currency usage.
Also, you can see, what this package doesn't have a currency settings on simple example in readme file:

```
// Add some items in your Controller.
Cart::add('192ao12', 'Product 1', 1, 9.99);
Cart::add('1239ad0', 'Product 2', 2, 5.95, ['size' => 'large']);
.....

<tbody>

        <?php foreach(Cart::content() as $row) :?>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p><strong><?php echo $row->name; ?></strong></p>
                    <p><?php echo ($row->options->has('size') ? $row->options->size : ''); ?></p>
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $row->qty; ?>"></td>
                <td>$<?php echo $row->price; ?></td>
                <td>$<?php echo $row->total; ?></td>
            </tr>

        <?php endforeach;?>

    </tbody>
```

As you can see in two last `<td>` used the dollar symbol ($) to show for users this prices are in dollars.

In my case, I used [russian roubles utf-8 symbol](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20bd/index.htm) and shows it in all views which has a price (product, product list, cart, order, etc).

Hope it helps you.)

Comment: Thank you. :) I didn't think of that .